how to calculate the UAVs energy consumed according to my parameters?
in my code I have some parameters , I have time limit , speed time , deadhead time . according to these how can i consume the energy for each uav according to the time limit?

service speed = 5 m/s
deadhead speed 8 m/s
time limit = 1800 seconds

I want to see according to the time limit that , how much energy each uav use? what formula I can use? how can i calculate the energy consumed?
